VS Code 1.94 - Run selection/line in Python terminal very slow
I've just started using VSCode (moving over from Spyder) and I regularly run lines/selections from my code in the terminal.
When I have a terminal open, shift + enter runs my selection in a new terminal and is incredibly slow.
The below takes about 5 seconds to send
 print(1)

If i copy and paste it in the new terminal, it runs instantly. Why is it slow? I want to continue using shift+enter to run my selection.
Why does it need to open a new terminal anyway? It can run in the existing terminal, where i start with
py

which begins a python interactive session.

you can look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79052807/vscode-spends-long-time-beginning-to-run-the-python-file/79052896#79052896

@Mohammedalmalki you have the option to delete your answer post there and post it here if you want people to see it here.

@starball should i delete it from there ? or i can just put it here also ?

As for the delay, according to this post on GitHub, the issue seems to be with the latest version (v2024.16.0) of the Python extension for VS Code. Downgrading it (and restarting the app) seems to do the trick for the time being.

Thank you, it worked!

It also worked for me! thank you so much
